# Refer asp:LinkButton inside a itemTemplate from code behind C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, webforms

I have a linkButton inside an itemtemplate that I want to change it's visibility depending on some condition, however, I cannot refer it in code behind using it's ID.

aspx(just a small example):

```
   <asp:gridview>
        <Columns>
           // BoundFields
             <asp:Itemtemplate>
                <div class="grid_buttons">//(just to style the buttons)
                  <asp:LinkButton ID="lb1" runat="server"></asp:LinkButton> 
                  <asp:LinkButton ID="lb2" runat="server"></asp:LinkButton>
                </div>
             </asp:Itemtemplate>
        <Columns>
       </asp:GridView>
```

code behind C#:

```
 if (condition){
 lb1.Visible = false;
 }
```

Comment: You have to look inside the specific row of the gridview and then find the control. You can't reference it directly because there will probably be several copies of the button, depending how many rows are in the grid. https://forums.asp.net/t/1079949.aspx?How+to+reference+button+in+grid+view+template+field+ (and many others...did you do any research?)

Comment: @ADyson I cannot refer a linkButton by it's ID when it's in itemtemplate have you even tried it? The server just doesn't regconize the ID as existing.

Comment: Read my comment again. You don't use the ID directly. First you get a reference to the row you want, and then you use FindControl within that row to get the specific instance of the button. The link I posted gives an example. I'm assuming you're doing this onRowDataBound or similar.

Comment: @ADyson I used the same code as the one in the link,(changed the grid ID and the row index) still when I write the ID it shows an error, should I pass pass the ID as a string? Button bt = (Button)(GridView3.Rows[0].FindControl("ButtonId")); and not like this?( Button bt = (Button)(GridView3.Rows[0].FindControl(ButtonId));

Comment: "should I pass pass the ID as a string" ...yes. You can easily [check the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.control.findcontrol?view=netframework-4.8) to see what arguments the FindControl method takes and what the types are. Or your Visual Studio Intellisense would have told you! In the example in that link I gave you, it's clear that `buttonId` must be the name of a string variable.

Comment: @ADyson Yeah thank you already figured it out :) thanks for your time